# Java - Class hierarchy, child classes containing different object types, and handling them from another class

Tags: java, generics, object, types

I'll try to be brief in the description of the problem...

A thread pool executes chained tasks. Each task inherits from an abstract class. Most of them deal with external services and need to be tailored to talk to the service. Each task will contain an object or list of objects, which we'll call TaskObjects, although they could be String, Integer, MyClass, etc. When a task completes, it places the TaskObject(s) and additional data into a collection of response objects and passes it on. When the chain of tasks completes, the collection is returned to the main thread.

The main thread will evaluate responses and determine what actions to take based on those responses. These may be immediate actions (ie, pull the TaskObject(s), manipulate them, and place the result into a new task for execution on the next available thread), or it may need to accumulate N responses of that type to trigger an action (ie, pull the TaskObject(s), possibly manipulate them, and place them in a local collection. If N TaskObject(s) build up in that collection over M time, an action is taken on those TaskObject(s)). Actions may also be based on where the response occurred in relation to other tasks in the response collection, so responses cannot handle themselves individually.

The problem I'm facing is dealing with a disparate bunch of TaskObjects. They do not inherit from any shared class (except Object, of course). Polymorphism wouldn't help. The nature of the evaluation at the main thread complicates things. I'm looking at options, but none of them seem very "good"...

- Delegation to the task/response to handle things, use a visitor, etc.
  This would be difficult as each task is not aware of anything beyond
  its own doings and what the next task will be. They'd have to tie in
  to some "centralized" service to handle the results, which would have
  to take thread safety into account, and having all responses bundled
  into a collection complicates things. Doable, but I could just be
  trading one mess for another.
- Generics. It could help flatten some hierarchy, but it would not
  solve the problem of the main thread dealing with TaskObjects as it
  won't know what type T is or how to handle it. Hello typechecking
  conditionals. Blech.
- Resign myself to typechecking the response objects outright.
- Create a wrapper for TaskObject(s) within the response that has
  fields for all types and place it in the abstract class. Now we get to nullcheck everything to find out
  what we're dealing with. Not much better.

I'm not sure if there is a "good" way to handle this sort of thing. The general problem isn't very unique in Java, but this particular predicament may be a bit more so. Perhaps there is no clean way to handle this and I just need to refactor a bit and implement the least-bad solution.

Then again, I could be overcomplicating things and a far better option is sitting under my nose...

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems to me that you have two places where the variety of tasks is visible: The task hierarchy itself and the response processing in the main thread. That means that adding a new task might require changes in those two places, which makes your code less flexible.

I wonder if you could encapsulate this variety in one place. One idea is to use Strategy Pattern: A strategy in this case would define the processing logic, which depends on the whole response collection. A specific Task class would just hold a reference to the strategy. That would require also creating an interface like `ITask` with one method, `getProcessingStrategy()`. In your case, the strategy interface would need to be able to accommodate your complex processing scenarios (e.g. `execute(Collection<IResponse>)`).

Eventually you would have a hierarchy of task classes and a number of independent processing strategies. Each task class would specify the strategy to be used. Adding a new task class would require a decision which strategy to process the task response with.